# Block specific URL in htaccess in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am using this code that blocks a URL with the word `foo`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo - [F]
```

It works fine, but, how do I make it work with the existing .htaccess code from WP which is below?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a case of putting that rule *before* the WordPress code block.

For example:

```
# Block all URLs that start with "/foo"
RewriteRule ^foo - [F]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

See also [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/376879/8259) to the following question on the WordPress SE site that goes into detail if you are still having problems:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/376875/blocking-access-to-all-post-tag-uris-via-htaccess

Comment: It is before the WP block, but what was lacking was `ErrorDocument 403 default`.